# having jquery events only work after 400 ms

Tags: jquery, events, timer

I have create an event on click

```
$('#next').bind('click', function(e) {
 //my animation event
});
```

the animations lasts for 400 ms - so i don't want th user to be able to click the next button until the animation finishes. is there a way to make the event handler inaccessible for 400 ms after the event fires?

Im sorry if this is obvious, but i struggled coming up with a google search. Maybe I'm missing some terminology.

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: `400` seconds?? Any way you can use `setInterval` to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @ujjawalKr its `400 ms`.

Comment: @Jai yeah that is what i thought. ;-)

Comment: but it looks like OP has some typo in this question.

Comment: Sorry - of course its 400 ms not seconds - i edited the q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
 var clickFlag=false; 
    $('#next').bind('click', function(e) {
  if(clickFlag==true)
      return;
  clickFlag=true;

  //my animation event

     setTimeout(function(){
     clickFlag=false;
       },400);
});
```

this may help you :)

Comment: Assuming 400ms instead 400s.

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly what I was after. I should have been able to think of that my self :) already using the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define a Boolean variable which you can set to true or false depending on whether the animation is currently happening or not:

```
var isAnimating = false;

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    // If the Boolean variable is set to true, prevent further execution
    if (isAnimating)
        return;

    // Set the Boolean variable to true
    isAnimating = true;

    // Animate for 400ms
    $(...).animate({
        ...
    }, 400, function() {
        // Set the Boolean variable to false after the animation completes
        isAnimating = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: better to use `.off()` method.

Comment: @Jai With that you'd have to redefine the `click` function every time which I imagine would be slower.